# Populate CheckboxList Based on URL Parameters

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to retrieve value from URL parameters and populate the value to a checkboxlist. Next step,  select the checkbox value, update the URL parameter. My sandbox  URL is https://oh2p2e.csb.app/?checkedCampusItems=A,B. Right now, it only works with one value in the URL. What is my problem? How do I synchronize the URL parameter value when clicking the checkboxlist? Many thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, if user checks for example option A, then url should be updated to something like this https://oh2p2e.csb.app/?checkedCampusItems=A ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://oh2p2e.csb.app/?checkedCampusItems=A,B

The A and B should be selected.

That means you should grab the 'checkedCampusItems', that will return you a string 'A,B'.

For example:

```js
// valuesToCheck is the array that contains
// the values from the url parameter
const valuesToCheck = checkedCampusItems.split(,);

// Now you can see which one should be checked.
// The three checkboxes will be rendered but
// the ones you want to will be checked.
<input type="checkbox" checked={valuesToCheck.includes('A')} onCheck={() => history.push(`/checkedCampusItems?=${currentValue},A`)} />

<input type="checkbox" checked={valuesToCheck.includes('B')} onCheck={() => history.push(`/checkedCampusItems?=${currentValue},A`)} />

<input type="checkbox" checked={valuesToCheck.includes('C')} onCheck={() => history.push(`/checkedCampusItems?=${currentValue},A`)} />
)
```

This is not the exact code, but you get the main point.

Comment: The checkbox works fine now. But I got the error  "TypeError history.push is not a function". Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `TypeError this.history.push is not a function` beacause you can't use `this` reference in a functional component.

Second thing, `useHistory()` is now deprecated, you can use `useNavigation()` instead.

To summarize, first add this line:

1. `import {useNavigation} from "react-router-dom";`
2. Then, change `input` element like this :

   ```
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
       name={name}
       value={name}
       checked={checkedState[index]}
       onChange={() => handleOnChange(value, index)}
   />
   ```
3. Change `handleOnChange` function like this:

   ```
   const handleOnChange = (value, position) => {
       const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
           index === position ? !item : item
       );
       setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
       // update URL params
       console.log(searchParams);
       navigation(`/?checkedCampusItems=${value}`);
   };
   ```

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxlist-forked-c1lt1x?file=/src/App.js:1513-1824